# Probability that Ken and John set next to each other

Tags: probability

> A group of ten people sits down, uniformly at random, around a table. Ken
>   and John are part of this group. Determine the probability that Ken and John sit
>   next to each other.

There are $10!$ ways to arrange the seating for everyone, there are 10 possible ways for John and Ken to sit together.

$$\operatorname{Pr}(J\ \&\ K ) = \frac{10}{10!} = \frac{1}{9!}$$

Am I correct?

Comment: There would be $10!$ ways to arrange the seating if they were in a line. (Not on a circle.)

Comment: $10/10! = 10/9!$ - what?

Comment: @SuzuHirose Hilarious typo!

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Two of nine people sit next to John.  The probability that Ken is one of these two is $\frac29$.

Comment: @Micah: Thanks for making the John/Ken fix.  I missed that one (obviously).

Answer (score 19):

Please take a look at [Circular Permutations](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CircularPermutation.html)

Total possible arrangements $$(10-1)!=9!$$

Consider $J$ & $K$ as one unit Now we'll have $9$ units then but (internal) arrangements of those two is not considered so favorable arrangements are
$$2!(9-1)!=2!8!$$

Hence $$P(A)=\frac{2!8!}{9!}=\frac{2}{9}$$

Comment: Thanks for pointing out circular permutations for me. I had no idea!